# How do I define date range sets based on the status of a user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and I have users that have gone from being active to inactive multiple times.  Usign TSQL my objective is to define the start and end date range of each active and inactive period for each user.  This is important because in later operations I'm limited in what can be applied based on just the active periods.  Listed below are a couple of tables illustrating what is given and the objective result I'm seeking.  A NULL for End date means this status is current and is interpreted as today's date using GETDATE().

Given: (Assume this source table is named, "User_Activity").

> [image: Blockquote]

Expected Result:

> [image: Blockquote]

Thanks in advance for your assistance.  I searched for other related issues but could not find anything.  Here is the SQL for creating the above source test set of data.

```
CREATE TABLE #User_Activity (
UserID INT
,[Start] DATE
,[End] DATE
,[Status] VARCHAR(10) NULL)

INSERT INTO #User_Activity (UserID, [Start], [End], [Status])
SELECT 1, '1/1/2005', '9/5/2006', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '9/6/2006', '4/2/2007', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '4/3/2007', '12/31/2007', 'Inactive' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '3/15/2009', '9/22/2009', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '9/23/2009', '12/31/2012', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1/1/2013', '8/15/2013', 'Inactive' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '8/16/2013', '5/31/2015', 'Inactive' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '6/1/2015', '2/5/2017', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2/6/2015', NULL, 'Active'
```

Comment: Could you please post some DDL and consumable Sample data please? I can answer this, but images aren't helpful in testing your answer first, and i'd rather not have to type out of of your data (it's much easier for you to do).

Comment: I don't understand how the  last line MaxEnd can be 12/20/2017, it's because if it's NULL replace by date of the day ?

Comment: That's correct.  The date range has not been closed out and I require the current date for use in later comparisons.

Comment: Annoyingly, you've providing your dates in `M/d/yyyy` format. This isn't going to work for me, as I'm English (there aren't 16 months in the year). I'll spend some time fixing this, but for future reference, whenever you provide dates on places like SO, SSC, etc, use the format `yyyyMMdd`. it will work, regardless of the user's language settings.

Comment: Wow!  Just run SELECT UserID, Start, End, Status FROM #User_Activty and it will display the dates in a YYYY-MM-DD format.  This is how it appears in my database table.  Your 16-month in a year comment makes no sense.  None of the month values are greater than 12.

Comment: @user3662215 yes, they are: `'8/16/2013'` for someone English translates into `20091608` Aka the 8th day, of the 16th month of 2009. I can't do a `SELECT * ` as running the OP's code in situ returns `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tested this for the full dataset, as I wasn't formatting all those dates, however, this should work:

```
CREATE TABLE #User_Activity (
UserID INT
,[Start] DATE
,[End] DATE
,[Status] VARCHAR(10) NULL)

INSERT INTO #User_Activity (UserID, [Start], [End], [Status])
SELECT 1, '20050101', '20060905', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20060906', '20070402', 'Active' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '20070403', '20071231', 'Inactive';
GO

WITH Grp AS (
    SELECT UserID,
           [Start],
           ISNULL([End], CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AS [End],
           [Status],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [Start]) - 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID, [Status] ORDER BY [Start]) AS Grp
    FROM #User_Activity UA)
SELECT UserID,
       MIN([Start]) AS MinStart,
       MAX([End]) AS MaxEnd,
       [Status]
FROM Grp
GROUP BY UserID, [Status], Grp;

GO
DROP TABLE #User_Activity;
```

Comment: Need to add a, `ISNULL`, fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not the best solution but serves the purpose in this scenario, please try following:

```
DECLARE @USER_ACTIVITY TABLE (USERID INT, [START] DATE, [END] DATE, [STATUS] VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @USER_ACTIVITY
SELECT 1, '1/1/2005', '9/5/2006', 'ACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '9/6/2006', '4/2/2007', 'ACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '4/3/2007', '12/31/2007', 'INACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '3/15/2009', '9/22/2009', 'ACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '9/23/2009', '12/31/2012', 'ACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1/1/2013', '8/15/2013', 'INACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '8/6/2013', '5/31/2015', 'INACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '6/1/2015', '2/5/2017', 'ACTIVE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2/6/2017', NULL, 'ACTIVE'

UPDATE @USER_ACTIVITY SET [END] = GETDATE() WHERE [STATUS] = 'ACTIVE' AND [END] IS NULL

;WITH CTE AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USERID, [STATUS] ORDER BY [START], [END]) AS R1,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY [START], [END]) AS R2
        FROM    @USER_ACTIVITY
        )
SELECT  USERID, MIN([START]) [START], MAX([END]) [END], [STATUS]
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY USERID, [STATUS], R2-R1
ORDER BY USERID, [START]
```

HTH!

Comment: The only limitation to this is that if source table User_Activity could not be modified, the UPDATE statement would not be an option.  In this case, the use of ISNULL in the SELECT statement example provided by Larnu avoids that situation.  I appreciate your help.